# How to improve drawn shapes in Quantum-GIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing, open-source-gis, map-drawing

I have a polygon-shape in qgis-1.7.0 and want to fix overlays and gaps between the edges of adjacent polygons. See image below.

[image]

Is there any automated way to do this in quantum-gis? Or any other F/OSS that can do things like that?

Any hints appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check out this video [Vector topology cleaning with QGIS and GRASS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YvEPOfSzhO0).it uses GRASS Toolbox v.clean which @artwork21 has mentioned.

> This video shows how to resolve a few common vector topology problems
>   using GRASS tools of the category "v.clean" through the Quantum GIS
>   interface.

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 3):

Import your vectors into GRASS (GRASS should be included in QGIS install) and use the [v.clean module](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.clean.html).  That should clean your topology errors.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in PostGIS [“Spatially clean” geometries with ST_SnapToGrid()](http://selectoid.wordpress.com/2008/11/26/spatially-clean-geometries-with-st_snaptogrid/) and [Removing small spaces between polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/removing-small-spaces-between-polygons)