# Adding attributes from surrounding feature (exclave problem)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, dissolve, adjacency

Here is the problem:

I am creating polygons based on the result of closest facility tool in Arcmap. Polygons consist of municipalities with the same closest hospital (impedance is a travel time, not a spatial distance).

Since there are some municipalities with really close highway entrances, there are "islands" or "enclaves" in my polygons. I need these islands to be dissolved in surrounding polygons. For better understanding see the pictures below.

[image: Picture 1: "Island"]

This is the example of a problematic municipality - "island" polygon

[image: Picture 2: Dissolve results]

Result of the dissolve tool. Dissolve field from the input feature is Obec_spado.

My idea is to add a new field. If a polygon is completely surrounded by polygons with only one "Obec_spado" value (as seen in in the pictures 1/2; = "island" polygons), which is different from the "Obec_spado" of an "island" polygon, value of that new field would be "Obec_spado" from the surrounding polygons. In other cases value of the new field would be the same as original "Obec_spado".

Does anybody know how to do it? Or maybe any other solution? Since I need to do it many times with different input data and do not know Python, ModelBuilder advices would be great...

Comment: The [q&a](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144218/removing-slivers-holes-from-polygons-using-arcgis-for-desktop/144225#144225) may help?

Comment: Try [Eliminate](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/eliminate.htm). You need to somehow select the islands first. You could try Dissolve (no multipart), Merge output with input, then Find Identical comparing geometries. The island geometries should stay unchanged when dissolving