# Merge hole between shapes into any neighbouring shape to remove it?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, holes

I have a shapefile that I made by from 2 distinct shapefiles (**I am using QGIS**). The issue is that they don't overlap precisely so I have holes like the following:

[image]

[image]

I tried the vertex editing tool but I have many shapes and that wont work. What I need is the hole below to be merged into any surrounding shape, like one shape gets extended to fill the gap, I don't want 2 distinct shapes to become one, but one or more to get bigger to fill the space.

I tried delete holes tool but that did not do what I wanted either.

Comment: have a look at the `snap` and `clean` algorithms in the processing toolbox.

Comment: I tried clean it gives me the error error while writing shapefiles, I checked the validity of the shapefile and it seems to be okay

Comment: You might create a new layer or a single large polygon larger than your combined data.  Then run a difference overlay of your shapefile with this new polygon.  Run the multipart to singlepart tool on the result.  Delete the "excess" poly in the singlepart layer outside your shapefile (you might need to cut it at the outer edge first for "indents" into your shapefile that you want to add) and then add the rest to your shapefile.  While these are selected run the Eliminate Selected Polygons tool.

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/402020/88814

Answer (score 0):

[This older GIS StackExchange question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/removing-small-spaces-slivers-between-polygons) has answers for multiple types of software, but in one of the comments they mention that in QGIS 2.18.1 'Eliminate Sliver Polygons' is available in the stable package and is found under Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools.

Comment: I use qgis3, I cannot find this under this menu

Comment: In my qgis2 I cannot see it as well

Comment: I don't have QGIS available to check right now, but a quick Google of "qgis eliminate slivers" finds the Geometry Checker Plugin (https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html), so maybe the tool has been moved elsewhere/incorporated into this plugin?