# Snapping parcels together using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, topology, snapping, parcel

I need to work with parcel data that comes from a variety of sources (private, gov, etc.). A lot of this is bad data where polygon boundaries overlap or do not snap together. I am finding it incredibly difficult to automate fixes for this using "validate" topology within a geodatabase.

I included an example of parcels within a single feature class that are then added to a topology, and I highlighted the type of topology gap error I'm dealing with. The fix to "create feature" does not effectively close this gap to create a coincident edge. Manual options such as "align edge" or "align feature" also do not snap these polygon edges together, produce errors, or are too time consuming.

Does anyone have a good process for this?

This seems like an incredibly basic and common task that is hard to figure out and automate.

I have an ArcGIS Pro Standard license.

[image]

Comment: How big is the typical gap (if there is one) and is your topology tolerance larger than that gap distance?

Comment: My xy tolerance is set to 0.0010000000 meters. Typical gap varies from less than 1m to 5m. I also tried the "Integrate" tool, but this did not close or eliminate the gaps and instead just erroneously reshaped the polygons.

Comment: Also, all above issues described are after getting the parcels into the same projection, merging them, and running "repair geometry" on that feature class.

Comment: With gaps that large the typical tolerance used in the Integrate or Validate processes wouldn't fix gaps, or it would change shapes more than you would like.  You could try a union of your parcels with a polygon for the whole municipality if you have one to fill in all the gaps.  Recalculate areas.  Select those under a certain size with no parcel info, run the Eliminate tool for selected features.  Like all auto tools you might not like what it keeps.  Here's an old thread you might get ideas from: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/removing-small-spaces-slivers-between-polygons